# Ordenar un array sin tomar en cuenta cadenas vacias

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo una consulta, sera posible hacer un orden alfabetico pero que si la cadena esta vacia no sea tomada en cuenta es decir:

Si tengo esto:

```js
    var items = [
          { name: 'Edward', value: 21 },
          { name: 'Sharpe', value: 37 },
          { name: 'And', value: 45 },
          { name: 'The', value: -12 },
          { name: 'Magnetic', value: 13 },
          { name: 'Zeros', value: 37 }
        ];
        items.sort(function (a, b) {
          if (a.name > b.name) {
            return 1;
          }
          if (a.name < b.name) {
            return -1;
          }
          // a must be equal to b
          return 0;
        });
        console.log(items)
```

Logicamente me ordena mi cadena de forma alfabetica pero si por alguna razon los datos que llego a obtener son los siguientes:

```
var items = [
  { name: 'Otro D', value: 21 },
  { name: 'Otro C', value: 37 },
  { name: 'Otro B', value: 45 },
  { name: 'Otro', value: -12 },
  { name: '', value: '' },
  { name: '', value: '' }
];
```

Es posible darle una instrucción al código para que no tome en cuenta los valores vacíos.

Comment: facil agrega al sort en el inicio `if (!a.name || !a.value) return 1`

Comment: Con esa sugerencia igual siguen saliendo los item vacios

Comment: es una forma de ordenar si quieres quitarlo usa el .filter

Comment: Qué quieres decir con que "no tome en cuenta"? ¿que se eliminen? de la lista

Comment: Si @PabloLozano que los elimine si no poseen contenido..!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La función `sort` ordena un array según el orden que tu función comparadora establezca, pero no puede eliminar elementos. Para eso existe la función `filter`:

```js
var items = [
  { name: 'Otro D', value: 21 },
  { name: 'Otro C', value: 37 },
  { name: 'Otro B', value: 45 },
  { name: 'Otro', value: -12 },
  { name: '', value: '' },
  { name: '', value: '' }
];
const resultado = items.filter(item => item.name).sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a.name > b.name) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a.name < b.name) {
    return -1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
});
console.log(resultado)
```

En este caso, los elementos pasan el filtro si su propiedad name no es vacía. Por otro lado, puedes comparar texto fácilmente usando el método comparador que ya trae la clase String:

```js
var items = [
  { name: 'Otro D', value: 21 },
  { name: 'Otro C', value: 37 },
  { name: 'Otro B', value: 45 },
  { name: 'Otro', value: -12 },
  { name: '', value: '' },
  { name: '', value: '' }
];
const resultado = items.filter(item => item.name).sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});
console.log(resultado)
```

Comment: el unico detalle y se que lo sabes el .sort quedaria mas elegante de esta forma `.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name));`

Comment: No, eso devolvería true o false, no 1, 0 o - 1, que es lo que se espera de esa función.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes solucionarlo con filter.

```js
var items = [{
    name: 'Otro D',
    value: 21
  },
  {
    name: 'Otro C',
    value: 37
  },
  {
    name: 'Otro B',
    value: 45
  },
  {
    name: 'Otro',
    value: -12
  },
  {
    name: '',
    value: ''
  },
  {
    name: '',
    value: ''
  }
];

let resultado = items
 //Eliminamos los vacios
.filter(x => x.name)
//Ordenamos en base a name
.sort((a, b) => a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1)

console.log(resultado)
```